# Access arguments of a function passed as argument

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to flip the parameters of a function passed to another function:

```
function dash(a,b) {
  return a + " - " + b;
}

function flipArgs(fn) {
  return fn;
}

flipArgs(dash)(1,2);
```

Currently it returns  "1 - 2", I need to return  "2 - 1". How can I access to the arguments passed to my "flipArgs" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
function flipArgs(fn) {
  return function(){
     return fn(arguments[1], arguments[0]);
  }
}
```

Of course, depending on your needs, you could use a larger swap, or test `arguments.length`.

Comment: @FezVrasta oups, fixed

Answer (score 2):

@dystroy answer is great, but there is a more generic way, take a look:

```
function dash(a,b,c) {
  return a + " - " + b + " - " + c;
}

function flipArgs(fn) {
  return function(){
    return fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.reverse.call(arguments));
  }
}

var r = flipArgs(dash)(1,2,3);
console.log(r); // 3 - 2 - 1
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3f4t919/1/

Comment: You should slice arguments then reverse it. Modifying the arguments pseudo-array leads to performance problems and isn't recommended. It also doesn't work the same in strict and non strict mode.